# What happens to the reference of an object managed by a unique pointer that has been moved?

Tags: c++, memory, unique-ptr

If I crate an object that is managed by a unique pointer such as:

```
auto pObjectA = std::make_unique<A>();
```

But I need this object as a parameter of another object:

```
auto pObjectB = std::make_unique<B>(*objectA);
```

If `objectA` is later moved with `std::move`, will the reference passed to `objectB` still be valid?

Edit:

```
class A
{
 //(...)
}

class B 
{
  public:
    B(A& objA): m_rObjectA(objA){}
    ~B();
    void DoSomehting() { /*something that calls a method in A*/ }

  private:
    A& m_rObjectA;
}    

int main()
{
  auto pObjectA = std::make_unique<A>();
  auto pObjectB = std::make_unique<B>(*pObjectA);

  std::unique_ptr<A> pA = std::move(pObjectA);

  pObjectB.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Short answer:  yes.   Moving `objectA` with `std::move()` does not affect the referred object.   It simply means that `objectA` can no longer be used to access it.

Comment: Does `objectB` hold a refernce to `*objectA` or a copy of it? You should share a [MCVE] to better illustrate your question. It is not clear to me what exactly you are asking.

Comment: Should `auto objectB = std::make_unique<B>(*objectA);` in fact be `auto objectB = std::make_unique<B>(objectA);`?

Comment: Thank you all for the replies! 
`objectB` holds a reference to objectA. So there is a member in B that is `A& m_rObjectA` I'll try to post a minumak reproducible example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the reference passed to `objectB` will still be valid since `std::make_unique<B>(*objectA)` will copy the object referenced by unique pointer `objectA` and use the copy object as its property instead of storing the original object. Therefore, if `objectA` is moved using the function `std::move`, `objectB`'s `A` object won't be affected. Here's the demo code for the affect of `std::move` on `objectA` and `objectB`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
  public:
    string value;
    A() {
      value = "ABC";
    }
    void print_values() {
      std::cout << "value: " << value << std::endl;    
    }
};

class B {
    A a_prop;
  public:
    B(A a) {
      a_prop = a;
    }
    void print_values() {
      a_prop.print_values();
    }
};

int main() {
  auto objectA = std::make_unique<A>();
  // objectB->a_prop will have a different A object from the one referenced by objectA
  auto objectB = std::make_unique<B>(*objectA);
  objectA->value.replace(objectA->value.begin(), objectA->value.end() - 1, "ED");
  objectA->print_values(); // Will display "EDC"
  objectB->print_values(); // Will display "ABC"

  // Object A that is referenced by objectA will now be referenced by objectAMoved
  // objectA will be nullptr
  auto objectAMoved = std::move(objectA);
  objectAMoved->print_values(); // Will display "EDC"
  
  objectAMoved->value.replace(objectAMoved->value.begin(), objectAMoved->value.end() - 1, "FG");

  objectB->print_values(); // Will display "ABC"
  objectAMoved->print_values(); // Will display "FGC"

  if (objectA == nullptr) {
    cout << "A is nullptr" << endl; // This will be printed out
  } else {
    objectA->print_values(); // This will cause segmentation fault
  }
}
```

Update: If you set `A& a_prop` and `B(A& a) : a_prop(a)`, it will still be valid but you will instead store the original object referenced by `objectA` in `a_prop` instead of a copy. After the object referenced by `objectA` is moved to `objectAMoved`, `a_prop` is still valid as it store the reference to original object `A` instead of a `unique_ptr<A>` like `objectA`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
  public:
    string value;
    A() {
      value = "ABC";
    }
    void print_values() {
      std::cout << "value: " << value << std::endl;    
    }
};

class B {
    A& a_prop;
  public:
    B(A& a) : a_prop(a) {
    }
    void print_values() {
      a_prop.print_values();
    }
};

int main() {
  auto objectA = std::make_unique<A>();
  auto objectB = std::make_unique<B>(*objectA);

  objectA->value.replace(objectA->value.begin(), objectA->value.end() - 1, "ED");
  objectA->print_values(); // Will display "EDC"
  objectB->print_values(); // Will display "EDC"

  auto objectAMoved = std::move(objectA);
  objectAMoved->print_values(); // Will display "EDC"
  
  objectAMoved->value.replace(objectAMoved->value.begin(), objectAMoved->value.end() - 1, "FG");

  objectB->print_values(); // Will display "FGC"
  objectAMoved->print_values(); // Will display "FGC"

  if (objectA == nullptr) {
    cout << "A is nullptr" << endl;
  } else {
    objectA->print_values(); // This will cause segmentation fault segmentation fault 
  }
}
```

Comment: In case B held a reference to A though, would it still hold? 
```
class B {
    A& a_prop;
  public:
    B(A& a) {
      a_prop = a;
    }
    void print_values() {
      a_prop.print_values();
    }
};
```

Comment: @j-hmd Yes, the object A is still accessible by `objectB` even after `objectA` is moved